# Cannot join two tables using indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I am just not able to get the table indexes to use themselves in this table join :

```
explain select n.* from npi n,npi_taxonomy nt where n.NPI=nt.NPI_CODE;
```

Here is the output of explain that i am getting :
[image]

As you can see, it finds the key in possible_keys column but the key column is empty. Please help.

Comment: that usually means that you do not have anything in NPI_CODE that matches to NPI. Are you sure that table npi_taxonomy is not empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query hits all rows in table `NPI` and you are selecting all columns from it.
Why would you want MySQL to use an index on that table?

I'm fairly certain that if you only included the column `npi` in the select list,you would get the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

why not use explicit joins

```
SELECT n.* FROM npi n  
INNER JOIN npi_taxomoty nt ON (n.NPI = nt.NPI_CODE)
```

or use a left join:

```
SELECT n.* FROM npi n
LEFT JOIN npi_taxomoty nt ON (n.NPI = nt.NPI_CODE)
```

If the first query returns **no** result, but the 2nd one **does**, you have no matches between n.NPI and nt.NPI_CODE.

As a side remark, I find it odd that you would give a field (NPI) the same name as a table (npi). It's confusing.